# Using multiple LIKE when selecting multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use multiple `LIKE` when selecting multiple tables. My SQL query is below.

```
SELECT users.*, threads.* 
FROM users, threads 
WHERE users.Username LIKE ? 
OR threads.Name LIKE ?
```

However, it works if I have only one LIKE, like this...

```
SELECT users.*, threads.* 
FROM users, threads 
WHERE users.Username LIKE ?
```

How should I go about using LIKE multiple times?

Comment: show sample input and output you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT users.*, threads.* FROM users, threads WHERE (users.Username LIKE ? OR threads.Name LIKE ?)
```

Comment: This is equal to the original query, the parentheses don't change anything.

Comment: I figured out the issue is with preparing the query in PDO. I did not pass a bindValue for the second ?. I will mark this answer to help any future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

check below query, I tried below eg. and it is working fine for me,

```
SELECT users.*, threads.* 
FROM users, threads 
WHERE users.Username LIKE '?' 
OR threads.Name LIKE '?'
```

eg.

```
select p.name,bi.mrp 
from billitem bi,product p 
where p.name like 'a%' 
or bi.productname like 'ta%'
```